# Grouping array based on an specific value

Tags: php

I have a basic array where I would like to group it based on the `x` field value. I would like to keep the values still in one array. I have tried multiple things foreach, for loops but no luck to get it how I would like. How can I achieve the below desired result?

```
$originalArray = [
    [
        'x' => 'test',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test2',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test2',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
];

Desired Result:
[
    'test'  => [
        [
            'x' => 'test',
            'y' => 'blah',
        ],
        [
            'x' => 'test',
            'y' => 'blah',
        ],
    ],
    'test2' => [
        [
            'x' => 'test2',
            'y' => 'blah',
        ],
        [
            'x' => 'test2',
            'y' => 'blah',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: If you have tried something, can you show us the code?

Comment: I agree with @Maxime in this case. You are saying "I have tried multiple things foreach, for loops". So show us. SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**. You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem. With that in mind, show us your own research efford.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this is what you want :

```
$originalArray = [
    [
        'x' => 'test',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test2',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
    [
        'x' => 'test2',
        'y' => 'blah',
    ],
];
$desired_array = array();
foreach ($originalArray as $key => $value) {
  $desired_array[$value['x']][]=$value;
}
var_dump($desired_array);
```

Comment: This is actually quite brilliant! Even if the input array is mixed up, this should still work. I'm impressed! +1

Comment: This worked amazing. As mentioned by icecub it is nice that even mixed up it still works.